# Connected Space with uncountably many path components

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, connectedness, path-connected

Here is a question I saw today: Provide an example of a connected topological space having uncountably many path components.

Actually I have came up with an example which I believe should be correct:

Let $T$ be a subspace defined by $T=\{(x,\sin {1\over x}):0<x\le 1\}\cup \{(0,y):y\notin \mathbb Q, -1<y<1\}$. Since $T$ is a subset of the closure of a connected set $\{(x,\sin {1\over x}):0<x\le 1\}$, which $T$ contains, it follows that $T$ is connected. Also, each point $a\in \{(0,y):y\notin \mathbb Q,-1<y<1\}$ forms a path component $[a]$. It then follows that $T$ has uncountably many path components.

I found this example by noticing that the topologist's sine curve has two path components, one of which ($\{(0,y):-1\le y\le 1\}$) fills up the closure of the other component( $\{(x,\sin {1\over x}):0<x\le 1\}$.)  When I take an uncountable collection of "separate points"  in $\{(0,y):-1\le y\le 1\}$, each of which is a path component, I would yield a connected set with uncountably many path components. I am just wondering if one could find an example for this problem in a different manner from mine, because my approach feels a bit unnatural.

Comment: That's a nice example. A bullet-headed approach: If $A$ is a connected space with two or more path components, we can take a disjoint union of an uncountable number of copies of $A,$ then take the quotient by identifying points in one of those components. So if $B$ is any uncountable discrete space, and $A_0$ is a path-connected component of $A,$ we take $A\times B/\sim,$ where $(a_1,b_1)\sim (a_2,b_2)$ iff $a_1=a_2$ and $a_1\in A_0.$

Comment: You can take an uncountable set, say $\mathbb{R}$, with the topology of countable complements (all sets with at most countable complement and the empty set).

Comment: Essentially, if $A$ is a space which is connected but not path-connected, then $A/\sim$ is the same, where $x\sim y$ iff there is a path from $x$ to $y.$ So we can always reduce such an example to one where each path-component is a single point.

Comment: Another Euclidean example, similar to yours, might be $$\{(0,0,z)\mid z\in \mathbb R\}\cup \left\{\left(x,y,\sin\frac1{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)\mid \frac xy\text{ irrational}\right\}$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Your space $A=\{1,2\}$ is path-connected.  More generally any connected finite topological space is path-connected.

Comment: Oh, whoops, will delete those comments. @EricWofsey

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-arc: it is connected and it's only path connected subsets are singletons and the empty set.

Comment: If each space $X_i$ is connected but not path-connected, then the product space $\prod_{i\in I}X_i$ is connected and has at least $2^{|I|}$ path components.